# Java to C# - sending/reading byte from jar server to C# client

Tags: c#, java, winforms, ascii, extended-ascii

I am writing a windows application. am having trouble in sending/receiving bytes from jar file.

jar file sends me a 2 byte [i.e.. !©]

i can read correctly the 1st byte since it comes within character code 0-127.
but for 2nd byte: the extended ASCII say"©" from a jar file, it comes into C# application as �

similarly when i send "©" to jar file, jar reads it as �

kindly guide me how to solve this problem.

am using this code for reading the byte from jar:

```
while (m_socClient.Available > 0)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int iRx = m_socClient.Receive(buffer);
    char[] chars = new char[iRx];
    System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
    int charLen = d.GetChars(buffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
    System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
    byte[] q1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(szData.Substring(0, 1));
    byte[] r1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(szData.Substring(1, 1));
    int qu = Convert.ToInt32(q1[0].ToString());
    int re = Convert.ToInt32(r1[0].ToString());   
}
```

am using this code for sending the bytes to jar:

```
var q = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(new byte[] { quotient });
var r = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(new byte[] { remainder });
Object objData_h = q.ToString() + r.ToString();
byte[] byData_h = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData_h.ToString());
m_socClient.Send(byData_h); // send the data to jar file.
```

Kindly help me please? How can i get the same character code in both C# and java??

Comment: 'jar file sends me' does not make sense, I suppose you retrieve the data via a TCP socket, correct?

Comment: You receive some data and interpret that as UTF-8 encoded text. Then you decode it with the Windows-1252 encoding. Characters are encoded differently in UTF-8 than in Windows-1252, that could explain why the bytes are different.

Comment: @home: Yup,am getting data through tcp.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problems with the encoding. Try doing this:

```
var q = new char[] { '!', '\u00a9'}; // u00a9 is copyright symbol in unicode.
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(q);
```

Check the byte array and you'll see it holds two bytes, 21 (which is !) and 3f where the second is not what you want. A copyright sign needs more than one byte but ascii are single byte.

Using

```
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(q);
```

Gives you three bytes for the two characters.